# Regular Expressions?

Tags: regex

I want to use Regular Expressions to match the string :

```
Tue Nov 25 2014 13:27:33 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.41.2.9.1 CIs-4509 supplies rated outputs do not match.
```

I try to use the regular expression :

```
(\S+) (\S+) *\s(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.41.2.9.1 (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)
```

But only match

```
Tue Nov 25 2014 13:27:33 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.41.2.9.1 CIs-4509 supplies
```

i want to retrieve these patterns as follow:

```
1.Tue
2.Nov
3.25
4.2014
5.13:27:33
6.CIs-4509
7.supplies rated outputs do not match.
```

How to get the rest string "supplies rated outputs do not match."  ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the matched part? Isn't 'rated' also in the current output? And lastly, do you understand what the current regex is doing?

Comment: @Jerry: indeed, one would expect the regex to match one extra word.

Comment: Your regex works pretty fine for me. Are you sure there is only one space between `supplies` and `rated`? Not a tabulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last group should be

```
.*
```

`.` means **any character**. By using an asterisks (`*`), you say *"any character and this any amount of repetitions"*

The full regex than reads:

```
(\S+) (\S+) *\s(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \.1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.9\.9\.41\.2\.9\.1 (.*)
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/wQ5bG9/1) provides a nice environment to learn about regexes as well to see how this regex is allied on your string.

Comment: Also, the dots should probably be escaped.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: indeed, although in this case, it wouldn't matter that much since the dot will unify with `.` ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
[\s\S]*?\.1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.9\.9\.41\.2\.9\.1[\s\S]*
```

You can try this as well.A short version of what you are doing.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/25

Comment: I've seen other places where people have used `[\s\S]` such as your `[\s\S]*` here. How is that different from just using "dot" as in `\.9\.1.*`?

Comment: @StephenP: `.` matches any character but newlines, etc. By using [\s\S] you capture absolutely everyting...